# ASP.NET MVC ViewService for Identity Server v3 from Thinktecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, thinktecture-ident-server

Currently looking into [Identity Server's](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3) implementation from Thinktecture and was curious does somebody tried to write his own [ViewService](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3/blob/master/source%2FCore%2FServices%2FIViewService.cs) instead of default [EmbeddedAssetsViewService](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3/blob/master/source%2FCore%2FViews%2FEmbedded%2FEmbeddedAssetsViewService.cs)?

I would prefer to have something MVC based that would allow to edit the pages with Razor syntax, as mostly all my applications are ASP.NET MVC, I think it would make sense to have this possibility... don't think it should be too hard, just curious if somebody already did it and could share any experience?

I tried to Google it, but didn't find anything about this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The github issue tracker is really the best place to directly connect with us.

And no - we don't support Razor - because IdSrv is not based on MVC - it is all Web API. We made that decision to suport single dll deployment and self hosting.

When MVC6 is available we will add razor support.

Comment: thanks for the answer... I understand the reasons why you do not currently provide Razor's support... I already finished my implementation and probably will publish the answer here as soon as finish other minor things. Probably somebody will find it useful while the general solution is not available.

Comment: Alex, can you please post your implementation, if you have finished.